pgfplots shader=interp seems to move the surface when using layers
When I use shader=interp as an option for a surface in pgfplots, if I have any layers set (even if I do not use them in that plot) it seems to shift the surface from where it should be. MWE below (my real use case is more complicated with lots of options, but I think I've boiled it down to the simplest thing that still displays the issue).
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{set layers=standard}

Where the surface should be:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot3[surf, domain = 0:2, domain y = 0:1] ({x*(1-y)},{y},{2-x*(1-y)-2*y});
  \draw[thick] (2,0,0)--(0,1,0)--(0,0,2)--cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Where the surface moves with \verb|shader=interp|:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, domain = 0:2, domain y = 0:1] ({x*(1-y)},{y},{2-x*(1-y)-2*y});
  \draw[thick] (2,0,0)--(0,1,0)--(0,0,2)--cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The output looks like this (the lines show where the boundaries of the surface should be):

In this example it seems to move the surface directly up (in the +z direction), but other surfaces in other viewing angles have moved in different directions.
By the way, removing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} seems to move it back, but it gives the warning Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} into your preamble. on input line 12. and seems to break other things in this and other plots.
Inserting \pgfplotsset{set layers=none} before or inside the second picture does not fix it.
I've hit my head against a wall long enough, and I'm tired of manually shifting the surface for every plot where I want shader=interp, so I thought I'd ask for some help. Thanks.
(Edit note: originally I thought it was that I had set custom layers, but I've now tested and found that even turning on the standard layers results in the same problem. So, layers with shader=interp seems to be broken?)

You can use backward compatible mode for the bounding box
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, compat/BB=1.7}

or you can set cell picture=true like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{set layers}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[cell picture=true]
\addplot3[surf, shader=interp, domain=0:2, domain y=0:1, samples=10] ({x*(1-y)},{y},{2-x*(1-y)-2*y});
\draw[thick] (2,0,0)--(0,1,0)--(0,0,2)--cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Here are the "Technical Internals" from the manual section 4.28 :

/pgfplots/cell picture=true|false|if necessary (initially true)
This
key is set automatically by pgfplots if necessary (for example by set
layers). Typically, pgfplots creates a so-called “cell picture”. A
cell picture is a separate picture which is typeset into a node.
Finally, the node is shifted to fulfill special anchor requirements.
The necessity for a cell picture is given if the anchor of an axis is
only known after the complete axis has been drawn. The initial choice
true means that pgfplots will create a cell picture for every axis.
This allows all anchors, but it is unsuited if multiple graphics
layers are desired or if one wants SVG export. In order to create a
cell picture, pgfplots interrupts the embedding tikzpicture, draws a
new tikzpicture, and finally typesets the result into a node. The
choice false tells pgfplots to draw its paths directly into the
embedding tikzpicture. Such an approach is necessary if the axis shall
use layers of the embedding tikzpicture. This is possible if and only
if the anchor can be determined without actually drawing the complete
axis. If so, pgfplots will modify the transformation matrix in
advance. Note that axes with cell picture=false will contain all the
usual anchors – the only difference is that the axis itself can only
use one of the following anchors for its alignment: north, north west,
west, south west, south, south east, east, north east, north, center,
origin, above origin, left of origin, right of origin, below origin.
The choice if necessary will check if the chosen anchor is one of the
list above. If so, it will use cell picture=false. Otherwise, it will
use cell picture=true.

The manual says cell picture=true is unsuited if layers are desired. I do not know why -it seems to solve the problem.
If this solution is not working, you need to ask a question, where the layers are actually used for something.

I'm satisfied with this. For the few graphs where I want shader=interp, I don't need layers. I just couldn't find a way to turn layers off for only one picture (since set layers=none did not work). I'm not sure I understand why this works. I guess since cell picture doesn't work with layers, it turns them off? Anyway, thank you!

I also do not understand cell picture - it is a part of "Technical Internals". Normally it is not needed to change anything there. Your example should be quite common though, so I suspect it is also a bug.

I mean obviously it is not intended behaviour, so a bug. -but I know that there are things that does not work well with cell picture (layers and anchors) and these things are by design and hard choices not working. Your example ought work, but does not.
